# Is possible to install Unsigned Application on Android 4.3?

Tags: android, unsigned

I know that to install an Unsigned application on phone, one need to select a option from setting "Allow Installation of non-Marked application", but this option is not available in my Samsung S3 phone.

How can I install an Unsinged Application ?

Comment: you can install apk file to your device

Comment: why don't you run the project on S3 device, the app installed will actually be an unsigned apk only

Comment: @krishna, I know, but it is not getting install.

Comment: did you saw this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_kwDPegCf0 ?

Comment: check your settings there you have checked some permissions uncheck one related to apps and then install

Comment: @SpringBreaker, Thanks, but that option is already `ticked` in my settings

Comment: Then it should install buddy. There might be some problem in your .apk. Check by using some other .apk files.

Comment: have you tried adb install?

Comment: Friends I have **4 Years experience** in Android. But this seems very strange problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install unsigned applications.

The "non-Market application" or "unknown sources" setting only allows you to install signed APKs from other sources than the Play store.

For non-release testing purposes including tracing with DDMS, sign your APK with a debug certificate. Android IDEs do it for you automatically.

For release purposes, sign your APK with a release certificate you've created yourself.

Further reading: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: I know singing process, but If I sign my application then I will not be able to trace it from DDMS.

Comment: Sign with a debug key then.

Comment: Aha.. that's correct & logical option. Can you update it in your answer please ?